# Calculate fourier transform in a certain interval

Tags: calculus, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

Calculate the fourier transform of

$$ f(t) = 
\begin{cases}
    b & \text{für } a \leq t \leq a+1 \\
    0 & \text{sonst}
\end{cases} $$

and write the result in a way, that we clearly see the influence of a.

So...

$$ F(\omega) = \int_{a}^{a+1} b e^{-i \omega t} dt = \frac{b}{-i \omega} (e^{-i \omega (a+1)} - e^{-i \omega a}) = \frac{b}{-i \omega} e^{- i \omega a} (e^{-i \omega} -1 ) $$

but what is the meaning of "the clear influence of a"...?

Comment: I would interpret "the clear incluence of a" to mean that it should be explicit what variables in the answer are dependent on $a$; ie. if other parameters had some dependence on $a$ this should be made explicit. I would say that in your solution one can clearly see the influence of a.

Comment: Note that we can write the Fourier Transform as 

$$\frac{b}{-i\omega}e^{-i\omega a}(e^{-i\omega}-1)=\frac{2b}{\omega}e^{-i \omega (a+1/2)}\sin(\omega/2)$$

Then, clearly the influence of the parameter $a$ is an additional phase shift.

Comment: It seems you are from Germany? ;)

Comment: I interpret the "influence of a" : What changing a will lead to to in the Fourier domain.

Comment: thank you! i see!